# AWS S3 | Access Denied while requesting image by URL | .Net Core

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, .net-core, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, asp.net-core-3.1

We have a S3 Bucket where we have stored images and we want to show these image on our Angular component by using image URL. But when we hit the URL , we are getting this error

**Error:**

> Requests specifying Server Side Encryption with AWS KMS managed keys
> require AWS Signature Version 4.

[image]

How can we load these images on our Angular component using URLs ??

Note: We are hosting this application on Elastic Beanstalk using .Net core project.

**Here is the bucket policy:**

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "BUCKETPOLICY",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "DenyInsecureAccess",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::dev-productimages",
                "arn:aws:s3:::dev-productimages/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "Bool": {
                    "aws:SecureTransport": "false"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

**Here is Encryption configuration:**

[image]

Comment: There are 2 things. Either you should use pre-signed URLs as the bucket seems to deny public access on it, or you should use CloudFront in front of your S3 bucket.

Comment: Pre-signed URLs for all the images ( we may have approx. 1K images) ? I will check for CloudFront

Comment: Ideally, if the images are not confidential then you should go with CloudFront, you will get server and client caching support by default.

Comment: If these objects are KMS-encrypted, the requester would need IAM permissions on the KMS key to decrypt them. Unauthenticated (public) users won't have that. Why are you KMS-encrypting objects that are going to be served publicly?

Answer (score 1):

When you upload the file, you need to set the acl to public read access

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet1/latest/apidocs/html/T_Amazon_S3_Model_S3CannedACL.htm

Example:

```
var transferUtilityRequest = new TransferUtilityUploadRequest()
            {
                InputStream = file.OpenReadStream(),
                Key = trustedStorageName,
                BucketName = bucketName,
                CannedACL = S3CannedACL.PublicRead, // Ensure the file is read-only to allow users view their pictures
                PartSize = 6291456
            };
```

Answer (score 0):

You're denying insecure access, but where are you granting access?

Without explicitly granting public access, your objects are accessible only to authenticated users from the owner account. I would rewrite as follows:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowAnonymousAccess",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::dev-productimages/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "Bool": {
                    "aws:SecureTransport": "true"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

**Very important:** note that I changed the action to `s3:GetObject`.

Comment: Good point, edited.