# Error in object URL of static website in S3 bucket: Requests specifying Server Side Encryption with AWS KMS managed keys require AWS Signature

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have created a static website in an S3 bucket AWS. I have created two files in bucket one in `index.html` and 2nd is `error.html`. When I open `index.html` and click on object URL in AWS it gives below error:

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
    <Error>
    <Code>InvalidArgument</Code>
    <Message>Requests specifying Server Side Encryption with AWS KMS managed keys require AWS Signature          Version 4.</Message>
    <ArgumentName>Authorization</ArgumentName>
    <ArgumentValue>null</ArgumentValue>
    <RequestId>R69TKNDJTYZ8E0SW</RequestId>
    <HostId>OAOZKRsA6ATOgH6jBr5jO1fS0zi+GSh4at34nLq8V/Ug8Icvuy8c6NOlCoNqqjpBcORg8bDlzJ0=</HostId>
   </Error>
```

I have checked every possible solution but nothing works. My bucket has public access like below my bucket name it is written in red Publicly accessible. But still I could not find what is issue.

Comment: The error says `Requests specifying Server Side Encryption with AWS KMS managed keys require AWS Signature`. Did you configure the bucket or objects to be encrypted? If so, why?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein what does it mean ?

Comment: Might help: [Is it possible to access to a public image in an KMS encrypted bucket without signature | AWS re:Post](https://repost.aws/questions/QUYnY0i0wiSReEm0J3xsEmyw/is-it-possible-to-access-to-a-public-image-in-an-kms-encrypted-bucket-without-signature) and also [AWS S3 | Access Denied while requesting image by URL | .Net Core - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71688083/aws-s3-access-denied-while-requesting-image-by-url-net-core)